# How to improve SEO ranking in a specific country?

Tags: seo, google-search, local-seo

I have a website that is struggling to rank up for a certain search in a specific country (Thailand in the specific case), and I am not really sure now what to do to improve the situation.

The strange fact is the following, given the search:

```
<service_keyword> <location>

<location> is a specific city in that country
<service_keyword> is an English keyword of a specific service we offer
```

the website rank in the top 10 results in many countries and even for google.com.

But for google.co.th the website is out of top 20 results (around 30th position now).

The website is in English, but I check that also many of my competitors also have the website only in English (not translated in Thai) so I don't believe that this is the problem, even if I agree that having the website in local language too could help.

The office address and telephone connected to the location used in search are there too, so I am lost.

The domain is .asia (not the country specific .co.th even if we own that the domain and it actually redirect to .asia)

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tactics you can take when localizing a website.
 1. host the site on local (Thailand) servers
 2. give the site a ccTLD
 3. create a version of the site in the native language with the native currency
 4. create geographically targeted paid ads

Moz had a great article about localizing websites:
https://moz.com/learn/seo/international-seo

Comment: Thank for suggestions, I analyzed top 20 results and most of them are hosted in United States as me. Only few are hosted in Thailand and Singapore. In the top 20 they don't have the specific ccTLD that is .co.th but most are .com. In addition most of them do not have Thai translation. I am already advertising my website in specific target location with Adwords but no improvements also with that trick.

Answer (score 0):

To improve geolocalization use geotargeting in Google search console. The location of the server is over nowadays (see [This note and linked article](https://hosting-international.com/#server-location))
Also helpful is if you have a Google my Business place in Google Map, embed that map in your contacts page.
Another note: as you have .asia, is there another website with the same domain as .com that operate in Thailand? Or somewhere else? As .asia is not a really geolocalization domain like .co.th if there is another website same domain .com that share common keywords Google could simply consider your one as a duplicate and privilage the one that older/better...
You could think about using .co.th instead of redirect that is the geolocalitazion domain for Thailand. But maybe you can share your domain as there could be other reason as you are not ranking well. 
For example, are you using a privacy whois (not a good seo practice)? If not, Are the Whois detail related to Thailand?